# How to tell webpack to drop bundles in a specific folder when watching?

Tags: webpack

I use webpack to bundle javascript that are part of a custom widget of a 3rd party host.

During *development*, I have to put the outputs in the host file system to test and debug in real condition.

How to tell webpack to copy the dist folder content in a network location, only when `webpack watch` command is used ?

I've read about [CopyWebpackPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/copy-webpack-plugin/) but it's stated not to use this plugin to copy build files.

If it matters, my current config is (typescript project):

```
import * as path from 'path';
import * as webpack from 'webpack';
import { CleanWebpackPlugin } from 'clean-webpack-plugin';

const config: webpack.Configuration = {
    entry: {
        'mywidget': './src/mywidget.ts'
    },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                use: 'ts-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
            },
            {
                test: /\.tmpl\.html$/i,
                type: 'asset/source',
                exclude: /node_modules/,

            }
        ],
    },
    plugins: [new CleanWebpackPlugin()],
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js'],
    },
    devtool: 'source-map',
    mode: "development",
    externals: {
        jquery: 'jQuery'
    }
};

export default config;
```

Basically, it bundles the `mywidget.ts` file and dependency from the `src` folder and outputs in the `dist` folder.

Comment: Read about it [writeToDisk](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverwritetodisk-)

Comment: I don't use the dev server. Basically, the bundled JS is hosted by the 3rd party app and registered by the host using a generated `<script src=...>`. I use webpack mainly because I want to have a single js output file.

Comment: If you are using the watch flag then use `nodemon-webpack-plugin` for this problem and run an external file which with nodejs will copy the changed data and save it to the server via ftp or whatever you use there.